# Locating Illegal State Exception Error

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, illegalstateexception

I am relatively new to java, and have developed a program that uses multiple regex expressions to find certain values from webpages. However, sometimes I encounter an error that states:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:468)
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:428)
```

My code contains a lot of regex, and I was wondering if there was a way in Eclipse to find specifically which pattern wasn't able to be found. Is there a way to find which line of code produced the error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you call `find` or `matches` on Matcher instance before using `group` method?

Comment: Yes, I was actually able to resolve the issue. The problem is that it took me a long time to solve because I use multiple pattern, matcher, find, and groups in my code. I was just wondering if Eclipse specifically states where the error occurred in my code. This way it wouldn't take me so long to resolve the issue in the future.

Comment: Somewhere below `at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:428)` you should have also something like `at your.package.name.YourClass.method(YourClassFile.java:XXX)` where `XXX` is line number in file `YourClassFile.java` where error was thrown. This line should contain `yourMatcher.group()` where `yourMatcher` either didn't invoked `find` nor `matches` methods, or didn't actually find any match for regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a check  before getting the group from the matcher otherwise it will result into below exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
```

Sample code

```
if(matcher.find()){    // you can use while loop as well if there is more matches
     matcher.group(1);
}
```

---

What [Matcher#group()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) method throws?

> IllegalStateException if no match has yet been attempted, or if the previous match operation failed.

What [Matcher#find()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) states:

> Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.
>
> If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the start, end, and group methods.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will be sure to do that. However, is there any information given by eclipse that will let me know where the error occurred? When I first saw the error I thought it meant the regex that wasn't able to be found was located on line 468. Does that information exist anywhere, or is it common practice to use a check?

Comment: Go down the stack trace that will tell you the exact location from where this exception is generating.

Comment: Always put a check before calling `group()` because there is no chance that there is any match. It's just like calling `next()` without calling `hasNext()` for IO in Java.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the help. Idk how I kept missing the location given in the stack trace, must have been working too fast and been too impatient. However, I'm still glad I asked to learn about checks. Thank you.